# How to find average of some inputs without using array in c++

Tags: c++

*Please do not copy and paste this as your own work*

This is what I got so far which is asking the user for the number of exam scores and depending on the score placing them into categories. After the run, I added how much scores there is for each category. Now I am trying to find the average score for each category after the run.

```
{
    int score = 0;
    int repeat = 0;

    cout << "How many exam scores?" << endl;
    cin >> repeat;

    int outstanding = 0;
    int satisfactory = 0;
    int unsatisfactory = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "Please enter an exam score:Don't Copy and Paste for Homework " << endl;
    cin >> score;

    for(int count = 0; count < repeat; count++)
    {
         sum += score
         if ( (score <= 100) && (score >= 90) )
          outstanding++;
           else if ( (score <= 89) && (score >=60) )
             satisfactory++;
             else if ( (score >= 0) && (score <= 59) )
               unsatisfactory++;
                 else if (score > 100)
                   cout << "ERROR EXAM THEY CHEATED GRADE INVALID" << endl;
         cout << endl<< "Enter the next score: ";
         cin >> score;


    }
    cout << "__________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "The number of Outstanding scores is: " << outstanding << endl;
    cout << "The average of Outstanding scores is: " << outstanding/sum << endl;
    cout << "__________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "The number of Satisfactory scores is: " << satisfactory << endl;
    cout << "The number of Satisfactory scores is: " << satisfactory/sum << endl;
    cout << "__________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "The number of Unsatisfactory scores is: " << unsatisfactory << endl;
    cout << "The number of Unsatisfactory scores is: " << unsatisfactory/sum << endl;
    cout << "__________________________________________" << endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What's going on with that spacing...

Comment: I'm just seperating what it outputs with a "____________" between them

Comment: I was planning on copying and pasting this as my own work.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you just need to add a few more variables. Using `int sumOutstanding = 0, sumSatisfactory = 0, sumUnsatisfactory = 0;`

```
for(int count = 0; count < repeat; count++)
    {
         if ( (score <= 100) && (score >= 90) ) {
           outstanding++;
           sumOutstanding += score;
         } else if ( (score <= 89) && (score >=60) ) {
           satisfactory++;
           sumSatisfactory += score;
         } else if ( (score >= 0) && (score <= 59) ) {
           unsatisfactory++;
           sumUnsatisfactory += score;
          } else if (score > 100)
           cout << "ERROR EXAM tHEY cHEATED GRADE INVALID" << endl;
         cout << endl<< "Enter the next score: ";
         cin >> score;


    }
```

Then just output the average just like you've already done with the sum integer.

Comment: I'm getting this error: expected primary expression before "else", expected ';' before "else"

Comment: @user3521657 So your missing a semicolon somewhere. Look at the line above where it's giving the error, and see if a semicolon is missing.

Comment: @David You forgot to put `{}` in your added statements and I edited.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a few variables to record the sum of different variables in every iteration. Using `int sumOutstanding = 0`, `sumSatisfactory = 0`, `sumUnsatisfactory = 0` as the previous answer; In every iteration of your `for` loop, you can keep track of the sum of each parameter and divide them by `count` in the end.

```
for(int count = 0; count < repeat; count++)
    {
         if ( (score <= 100) && (score >= 90) ) {
           outstanding++;
           sumOutstanding += score;
         } else if ( (score <= 89) && (score >=60) ) {
           satisfactory++;
           sumSatisfactory += score;
         } else if ( (score >= 0) && (score <= 59) ) {
           unsatisfactory++;
           sumUnsatisfactory += score;
          } else if (score > 100)
           cout << "ERROR EXAM tHEY cHEATED GRADE INVALID" << endl;
         cout << endl<< "Enter the next score: ";
         cin >> score;
    }
```